# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "ayudar" y "coadyuvar"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, sinónimos, acepciones

Mirando el diccionario vemos dos definiciones de palabras parecidas:

> [***coadyuvar***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9WCAeFL)
>   *De co- y el lat. adiuvāre 'ayudar'.*
>   1. intr. Contribuir o ayudar a que algo se realice o tenga lugar. *Su conducta coadyuvó a despertar sospechas*. Era usado también como transitivo

y

> [***ayudar***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4cSgffR)
>   *Del lat. adiutāre.*
>   1. tr. Prestar cooperación.
>   2. tr. Auxiliar, socorrer.
>   3. prnl. Hacer un esfuerzo, poner los medios para el logro de algo.
>   4. prnl. Valerse de la cooperación o ayuda de alguien.

La etimología es muy parecida (una surge de la otra), pero *coadyuvar* la suelo encontrar en textos más técnicos (véanse las [entradas del diario El País donde aparece](https://elpais.com/buscador/?qt=coadyuvar&sf=1&np=1&bu=ep&of=html), generalmente de temas legales). Pese a ello, el DPD tampoco habla sobre este tema:

> [**coadyuvar**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=coadyuvar). ‘Contribuir o ayudar a la consecución de algo’. Es intransitivo y se construye con un complemento introducido por a o, a veces, en: «*La consigna es coadyuvar a una gestación más feliz*» (RdgzEglis Educación [Arg. 1985]); «*Manifiesto mi voluntad de coadyuvar en la aclaración de esta situación*» (Proceso [Méx.] 17.11.96). Son incorrectas las formas coadyudar o coayudar, fruto del cruce con ayudar.

La mayor fuente de conocimiento al respecto de su diferencia la encontré [en Yahoo respuestas](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080319230739AAjxFPV):

> — ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ayudar y coadyuvar?
>   — unas cuantas letras

Así pues, ¿existe alguna diferencia entre ambos conceptos?

Comment: Mmmm ¿no creéis pertinente crear una etiqueta del tipo [tag:diferencia-entre-palabras] para casos así? El etiquetado me quedó corto

Comment: Yahoo respuestas nunca defrauda xD. Yo la diferencia que veo es que *coadyuvar* es una ayuda muy específica: _«ayudar a que algo se realice o tenga lugar.»_ Es una ayuda dirigida a un fin

Comment: Para mi son sinónimos. No conozco ningún diccionario **oficial** de sinónimos pero los no-oficiales lo dan por sinónimo también. https://www.sinonimosgratis.com/coadyuvar

Comment: Nunca he usado *coadyuvar* pero puedo imaginar su uso en una situación, en que quisiera reconocer la aportación de Persona C, que aportó algo diferente que Personas A y B que también apoyaron el proyecto a su manera.

Comment: @walen hay [bastantes preguntas que consultan la diferencia entre palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22diferencia+entre%22) y veo algo de cacao entre [tag:uso-de-palabras], [tag:selección-de-palabras], [tag:sinónimos] y [tag:definiciones]. Lo plantearé en Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre he entendido como que quien **ayuda** está involucrado directamente en la solución de un problema que otra persona individualmente o un grupo de ellas no pueden resolver por si mismas.

Quién **coadyuva** lo hace indirectamente, pero de forma inconspicua, al favorecer o crear las condiciones necesarias para que los que **ayudan** tengan mejores probabilidades de tener éxito.

Por ejemplo, el caso ficticio de un grupo de migrantes que caminan por el desierto  para evitar ser deportados. Y no tienen agua para beber.

La brigada de rescatistas les **ayudan** proporcionando primeros auxilios, suero y transporte para recibir atención médica.

Los miembros del patronato de "*Ángeles del desierto AC, rescatistas*" cada mes donan una cantidad de sus rentas para la operación de los rescatistas. Ellos, con sus donaciones, fueron **coadyuvantes** del exitoso rescate.

Pero también fueron **coadyuvantes** los guardias de la propiedad privada que a riesgo de su propio empleo, abrieron las puertas y permitieron a la brigada pasar sobre un terreno privado en contra de las instrucciones de su patrón con el  fin de que los auxilios no demoraran más. Los guardias fueron **coadyuvantes en el rescate**.

:)